# String NULL OR EMPTY

Tags: c#, string, isnullorempty

I am doing Api Testing in Ranorex , there is one Test-Case where i have to keep a check that empty string should not be acceptable and if in anycase it would be empty then the error should reflect about empty string and TC have to have fail

At what scenario the Null string or empty string could be utilize in best way , I already read some post on internet but i still have some doubts what to use when

```
public static void SetStringContent(string content)
{
    _request.SetStringContent(content);
    Report.Info(_category, string.Format("Request content (string) set to '{0}'.", content));

    // Testcode for checking if String is Null or Empty it will reflect an Error.
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
    {
        Report.Error (_category,string.Format("is null or empty.",content));
    }
    else
    {
        Report.Info (_category,string.Format("(\"{0}\") is neither null nor empty.",content));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IsNullOrEmpty is a useful method that allows you to simultaneously test whether a String is null or its value is String.Empty.

or you can use this method if blank values ​​can arrive in your api.

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String) Method
```

It is true if the value parameter is null or Empty, or if value consists only of white space characters.